# Where is the mobile preview editor

Tags: android-studio

I believe that I have accidentally closed the layout editor in Android Studio. How do I get it back without having to restart Android Studio?
Note, I have refreshed the Android Studio and that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you closed your design tab (or so it seem from your question) you can go back to it by click on the left bottom corner `design` tab

[image]

If you want to re-open the preview you just need to press the preview tab (see image) :

[image]

And if you don't see the preview tab at all you can pop it up like this :

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Preview
```

[image]

Comment: The issue here is that the design tab and the preview tab is also gone.

Comment: I finally figured out the solution, I had to navigate to src>main>res>layout

Comment: so you never lost your layout editor, you were just In the wring place in the app

Comment: I had to reopen the tab via those folders, what happened was that I accidentally closed the tab and did not know where to do to get it back. But I have figured it out. Your screenshots guided me as well.

Comment: Just to make something clear - you had to open some specific layout tab and in this tab, you had its layout editor/preview. every layout got its own preview.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem please accept it so others can know to use it